# error  Invalid Call Back URL Failed in Flickr API

Tags: iphone, objective-c, flickr

I need to implement flickr in my app.i just downloaded the api.In that i founded the sample(SnapAndRun).That sample is working,but i am getting issues saying that call back URL failed .please let where i have to modify it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to set up this URL on the Flickr website against your app. It is the url that Flickr will call after user authentication. This will be your application's custom url scheme. But for the example application, you will need to set it up as `snapnrun://auth?`.

Comment: hi deepak thanks for u r reply..i just have kept this url in .plist of my application but i am getting same error..the application url is http://www.flickr.com/auth-72157626801222124.please let me know how to use this urll.